# Redirects from robots.txt to robots.php in nginx

Tags: php, nginx, redirect, centos, robots.txt

I use CentOS7 with nginx. I need dynamical robots.txt for this I try to use redirect from robots.txt to robots.php. But in case site.com/robots.txt I see text from file robots.php and in case site.com/robots.php I see results of run this program. How I can fix it that site.com/robots.txt give me result of run robots.php?
In nginx i use next code:

```
location /robots.txt { alias /home/xxx/web/site.ru/public_html/robots.php; }
```

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^/robots\.txt$ /robots.php last;`

Comment: Yes! It's works.

Answer (score 0):

While `rewrite` approach as in comments would work, it's worth noting that the proper solution is exact matching location which unconditionally directs requests to PHP-FPM, like so:

```
location = /robots.txt {
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/robots.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    # override SCRIPT_NAME which was set in fastcgi_params
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /robots.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/example.com.sock;
}
```

Comment: I have installed vestacp control panel and in my server dont exist file /var/run/php-fpm/example.com.sock. exist only /var/run/vesta-php.sock but wit him dosent works - error 500